# How can I configure AWS Fargate to allow inbound traffic using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I am trying to get started with AWS Fargate (using aws cli to be able to script things) and have got my service to start and I can see from the logs that it executes.

However when I connect to the public IP of the task I do not get any response on the ports the container is listening on. The container works locally.

How can I configure AWS Fargate to allow inbound traffic using aws cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that the default security group did not allow inbound traffic. The following commands allowed me to find which security group was used by my VPC as well as allowing all inbound traffic to that VPC.

aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=$vpcid

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $secgroup --protocol tcp --cidr 0.0.0.0/0 --port 0-65535

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, problem related to security group configuration issue.
You have to enable the port which your container is using.

You can create or update current security group to allow the port to be accessible from the outside of your VPC.

For creating new security group: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-security-group.html

For updating current security group:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/update-security-group-rule-descriptions-ingress.html

For updating ECS service's security group:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html